# AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest reverting to placeholder when scrolled past

Tags: iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

- I am making a simple reddit app for a school project. I am loading my
  data from reddit via json (http://www.reddit.com/.json for example) with `AFNetworking` library.
- I am displaying each reddit thread with a prototype cell, which
  contains a `UIImageView` for the post thumbnails.
- I am trying to use `AFNetworking` to lazy load the images, with the
  `setImageWithURLRequest` method.

**the problem:** when the app launches all the thumbnails load lazily as they should as I scroll down the tableView. As soon as the cell is out of the view and I scroll back up to it, the thumbnail has been replaced with the placeholder image -- even though it loaded the correct thumbnail before scrolling past.

Relevant code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. the lazy loading is being called in the `setImageWithURLRequest` block

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"threadCell";
    SubredditThreadCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary   = [self.subredditArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *singleThreadDict = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

    if ( [[singleThreadDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] isEqualToString:@"nsfw"] ){
        cell.postImageThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NSFWIcon"];
    }
    else if ([[singleThreadDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] isEqualToString:@"self"]){
        cell.postImageThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selfIcon"];
    }
    else if ([[singleThreadDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] length] == 0){
        cell.postImageThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"genericIcon"];
    }
    else{
        NSURL   *thumbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[singleThreadDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] ];


        [cell.postImageThumbnail setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:thumbURL]
                                 placeholderImage:nil
                                 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                                    {
                                        if (request) {
                                            [UIView transitionWithView:cell.postImageThumbnail
                                                    duration:1.0f
                                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                    animations:^{
                                                        [cell.postImageThumbnail setImage:image];
                                                    }
                                                    completion:NULL];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"failure loading thumbnail");
                                    }
         ];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In your last else block , it sould be "  else if(cell.postImageThumbnail.image == nil) " so if image is downloaded , it won't make a request to redownload...

Comment: hi, I've made the change you suggested, but the images still seem to be replacing themselves. I think it may have to do with what Vincent Gable (first answer) mentioned.. Any insight into that? Thank you

Comment: reading your code again , i came to know , you didn't allocate or initialize the cell , if cell == nil , then you need to load from bundle (in case of customcell and nib) or alloc , init.

Comment: see this http://pastebin.com/9r8AMaim , see line 6 - 11 and line 25 , i did what i mentioned above

Comment: if it gives warning in SubredditThreadCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; , you need to typecast it then..

Comment: @HarshIT thanks for the input. There's no stand-alone nib for the custom cell. I just dragged a table view with a prototype cell out in story board, and then set the class to the custom cell class `SubredditThreadCell`. not sure what I'd change the `cell = self.objCustomCell` line to?

Comment: @HarshIT I am also getting a warning on the line `[UIView transitionWithView:cell.postImageThumbnail`. The warning reads: `Capturing "cell" strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle.`

Comment: if no nib is there then you should alloc init the cell's object in the block where cell is nil (in my code, instead of those 3 lines). to remove warning give weak to your cell , probably it may remove warning

Comment: Actually i used to load my custom cell from Nib so i pasted that code

Comment: this is what I have.. not sure what I'm doing wrong but no change
http://pastebin.com/FBXQbcBB

Comment: its used for default tableviewCells , probably it will work fine, in fact i don't know how you are using/creating custom cell so can

Comment: im just using storyboard builder.. Dragged out a table view controller, which created a prototype cell. then I just edit the cell in the builder, and linking it to the class. Here's a visual: http://i.imgur.com/UqD7qAH.png

Comment: ok in that case , I am sorry, I am not familiar with storyboards. But normally we check if cell is nil , we give it memory and initialize it. in your case while scrolling the cell is reinitialized and allocated memory (instead of reloading the cell it creates a new one).  That's the actual problem.

Comment: I see, that certainly sounds like the problem. Any ideas what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't directly update the cell's postImageThumbnail when the image is done downloading.

Instead, tell the UITableView to refresh just that cell, using `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

To get better performance, UITableView will re-use a cell-object once it's been scrolled offscreen, to show different data that is currently visible. (This is why `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` starts with "dequeueReusable", instead of "makeNew".) This lets UITableView only create about as many cells as are visible, instead of having to create and destroy as many cells as there are rows in the table.  By the time your networking request succeeds, the `cell` that the `success:` block captures is being used to display another row, and you're over-writing *that* row's image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. 

if I understand correctly I need to change the line in the 
`[cell.postImageThumbnail setImage:image];` to something like
`NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];`
`[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

although it doesnt seem to work. Any other input appreciated :)

Comment: You understood correctly. I'm not quite sure what's going wrong, the expectation is that after asking for a row to be reloaded, cellForRowAtIndexPath will get called and you'll get a chance to give out a cell for it, but this time you'll have an image ready. Try setting a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and step through to see if anything is going wrong. Also, you shouldn't need the transitionWithView block anymore.

Comment: I'll keep messing with it, thanks. Where should I ultimately be assigning the image to the ImageView if not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is where you configure your cells. UITableView will manage only calling this method if it needs to, so you don't have to worry about doing work updating a view that isn't shown. I'm suggesting making sure that the next time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, you will have all the information you need to update your image there.